# Modify z-order of android Views, before launching an animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, z-order

I'm trying to set an animation in one of my gridview's item, and I'm stuck with the z-order. In fact, when I execute my animation (from a `onItemClickListener` of the GridView), the item is under (in z-order) than the next one, and I'd want it to be on the top. I tried using `bringToFront()` on that item, but it kinda send it to the end of the GridView, so it is not what I'd like to do.
Do you have any idea of how I could modify the z-order of those GridView items ?

**Edit:** Actually, it seems to concern all Views, and not only Gridviews. In fact, Itried something with a `FrameLayout` : when I don't do anything, it goes under other objects, and when i use `bringToFront()`, the FrameLayout disappear. Quite weird !